# Retrive data from reusable widget Textfield

Tags: dart, flutter

In the following code, I am trying to get text by using controller `data` or by using `var abc`, abc is defined globally, 
At the end of process I get `null` only.
Nither of `data` or `var abc` is working.

```
Widget _textField(BuildContext context, String label, TextInputType inputType,
    TextEditingController data) {
  return Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
    child: TextField(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
      controller: data,
      onChanged: (text) {
        abc = text;
      },
      keyboardType: inputType,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          labelText: label,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
          )),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: from where you are calling "_textField" method?

Comment: Can you posy the code showing where you call this widget

Comment: in StatefulWidget